# Autoload controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, autoload

I have question to you. 
I try add to my page calendar and some events in this calendar. I know how I can load calendar in page, but I didn`t now how I can load this calendar on every page automatically.

Controller:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Calendar extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $data = array(
                3  => 'Polska - Anglia',
        );

        $this->load->library('calendar');

        $vars['calendar'] = $this->calendar->generate('', '', $data);

        $this->load->view('main/calendar', $vars);
    }
}
```

and In view I call:

```
<?php echo $calendar;?>
```

I use CodeIgniter 2.1.3

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating controller for calendar, create a library class and then add it to autoload configuration file

```
class MyCalendar{

public function get()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance(); 
        $data = array(
                3  => 'Polska - Anglia',
        );

        $CI->load->library('calendar');

        return $CI->calendar->generate('', '', $data);
    } 
}
```

Add this library to autoload file and then you can call it anywhere you want by using this statement.

```
$data['calendar'] = $this->MyCalendar->get();
```

Comment: I add this code and now I have error: `Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$MyCalendar` I call by: `$data['calendar'] = $this->MyCalendar->get();
echo $calendar;`

Comment: @marcin_poland You must use the lower case version. `$this->mycalendar->get();`  It's writen [right here under using your own class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) .

Answer (score -1):

You can autoload your library by changing the `application/config/autoload.php` file.

Find :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array();
```

Replace by :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('calendar');
```

To load the same calendar on all your pages, I suggest to build a parent controller in the `application/core` folder.

```
abstract class BaseController extends CI_Controller
{
    protected $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data = array();    

        $calendarData = array(
            3  => 'Polska - Anglia'
        );

        $this->data['calendar'] = $this->calendar->generate('', '', $calendarData);
    }
}
```

You can then extend that `BaseController` class on all your controllers.

```
class Calendar extends BaseController {

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('main/calendar', $this->data);
    }
}
```

Be sure to always use `$this->data` to build on the protected member of your class.

Lastly, your `BaseController` will not be autoloaded, you probably don't want to include it everywhere.  I suggest you to add the following method at the end of your autoload or config file.

```
/**
 * Extra autoload function. Loads core classes automatically.
 * @param type $class The class to load.
 */
function __autoload($class)
{
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT))
        {
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to autoload any classes you have in your `application/core` folder.  This solution might seems complex, but once it's setup.  You can add functionality to your `BaseController` that is applicable for all pages, for example, header and footer stuff.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I try it, but this not working. I have error `Message: Undefined variable: calendar`

Comment: Are you trying to output your calendar (always the same) on all your pages?